# How to detect the changes in @input attribute when the same value is sent from parent

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-changedetection

I researched and none of them was able to give me correct solution for the problem.
I have 2 components named parentComponent and childComponent.

childComponent.html

```
     <div *ngIf="isShowMessage">
       <p>Hey i was told by parent component to be shown Here i am !!!</p>
         <button (click)="cancel()">cancel</button>
     </div>
```

childComponent.ts

```
     _isShowMessage = false;

     @Input() set isShowMessage(value: boolean) {
          this._isShowMessage = value;
     }
      get isShowMessage(): boolean {
            return this._isShowMessage;
      }
     cancel(): void {
      this._isShowMessage = false;
      this.isShowMessage = false;
    }
```

ParentComponent.html

```
      <childComponent [isShowMessage]="isShowMessage"></childComponent>
      <button (click)="handleClick()">save</button>
```

ParentComponent.ts

```
        isShowMessage = false;
        handleClick(): void {
          this.isShowMessage = true;
         }
```

Step 1:
when i click save button from parent , child component div is shown:

```
     <p>Hey i was told by parent component to be shown Here i am !!!</p>
```

Step2:
When i click cancel button from child component, the div is hidden.
   [expected Behavior]

step 3:
when i again click save button from parent , child component div is NOT shown.

is it due to same value true sent second time as well? not sure ...
any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: ngOnChanges triggered in the child component on step3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this approach:

ParentComponent.html

```
<childComponent #child></childComponent>
<button (click)="handleClick(child)">save</button>
```

ParentComponent.ts

```
handleClick(child): void {
  child.isShowMessage = true;
}
```

Comment: this approach works but how? could you please explain ?

Comment: changing `child.isShowMessage` is fundamentally your goal. and this approach doing that directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending ShowMessage from parent to child and accordingly you are making changes in child component .then if any event happen in child let the parent know by emmiting event so parent will be in sync with child and if parent again change that value in that case child will get that value.

**Check below edited code**

childComponent.html

```
 <div *ngIf="isShowMessage">
   <p>Hey i was told by parent component to be shown Here i am !!!</p>
     <button (click)="cancel()">cancel</button>
 </div>
```

childComponent.ts

```
     _isShowMessage = false;

     @Input() set isShowMessage(value: boolean) {
          this._isShowMessage = value;
     }
    @Output() hideParentValue = new EventEmitter();
      get isShowMessage(): boolean {
            return this._isShowMessage;
      }
     cancel(): void {
     //comment this below code 
     // this._isShowMessage = false;
     // this.isShowMessage = false;

     //add this 
     this.hideParentValue.emit()
    }
```

ParentComponent.html

```
  <childComponent [isShowMessage]="isShowMessage" 
     (hideParentValue)="hideMessage()"></childComponent>
          <button (click)="handleClick()">save</button>
```

ParentComponent.ts

```
 isShowMessage = false;
        handleClick(): void {
          this.isShowMessage = true;
         }
         hideMessage():void {
          this.isShowMessage = false;
         }
```

If still there is issue then you can make child component to implement OnChanges interface and then implement ngOnChanges function and put debugger over there.

if input change debugger should hit .. you can find root cause of your problem by this lifecycle hook.